# How to distribute my finished app without app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

As the title states, I have been developing and testing an app for Iphone. I have got it to install to an iphone via it being plugged into the Mac. But, I would like to get the app place it on my webserver then via a website allow someone to download and install the app. I tried following various tutorials, but as shown below after archiving the app, the export and other buttons are greyed out. Have also made sure 'Generic iOS devices' selected. What could be causing this ?

[image: The greyed out export button]

Comment: Based on your comment under one of the answer: what you want **cannot** be done - period! Some people with jailbroken devices might be able to do it, but the *normal* user cannot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Apple TestFlight or use a third party service to allow your beta to be distributed for testing. One good service is HockeyApp, which I am using currently and it is very cheap $10/month.

Comment: Sorry if i sound clueless, but I have tested the app and it is all tickety boo (sorry for being cliche). What i'm after is to now simply place a link on my site, which when clicked will download the app for people( whom will be clients of mine) to download the app.

Comment: Hi Vaishal, for final distribution Apple allows only apps to be distributed through the App store, because of course they want to get a cut of it, and also because they want to have control over the quality. But they do understand that people need to test apps on devices before they publish, so they have a program called Testflight that allows distribution to devices that are registered for testing. Please read https://developer.apple.com/testflight/. You would need to register as a team org, and create a team profile for adhoc testing, which would include the UUID of your testing devices.

Comment: By the way, if you don't know the UUID of the devices, the HockeyApp services provides a way for your target tester to respond to an email request which would collect the UUID of the person's device automatically and load it in the HockeyApp system.The profiling file that is used to check whether a device is allowed to run an app during development needs to have UUID of the device, so I don't think you can avoid this step. Hockeyapp will provide you with a public URL from which to have your testers download your app.Just go to hockeyapp.com and read a bit about how that works. It works great

Answer (score 1):

What is causing this may be that you are not enrolled in the correct Apple developer program.

A stock iOS device will only install an app from a link on a website if the app is signed by certificate from an Enterprise Developer program enrollment (or Ad Hoc provisioned).  The Enterprise distribution method is only allowed to employees of the enrolled corporation.

Ad Hoc deployment to devices registered to your enrolled Developer account is also supported by stock iOS devices.

One other possibility is to put a link to your entire Xcode project on your website, with instructions on how anyone with a Mac and Xcode can build your app and then run it on on their device.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the UDID of your client, you simply can't!